# merge a query to a connection in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am working with a Pivot table in Excel that uses a connection to a SAS db.  I want to join in a few of my own tables to the connection to add to the pivot table, and have added them into different tabs in the Excel workbook and then use the Get Data feature to import them into the data model.  However, it won't let me merge any of the new tables with the original connection.  Is there a way to do this?

There is no way for me to alter the SAS db as its owned by a different team in my organization.

Comment: Check the column types in each table and specifically the ones involved in the merge

Comment: It won't even let me select merge - it's not that the merge is failing.